# Chrome does not send cookie

Tags: angular, google-chrome, authentication, cookies

I am trying to post data to server with angular 5.
My code is:

```
createProfile(newProfile: NewProfile) {
    this.http.post<NewProfile>(this.messageUrlPost, CreateFormData.createFormData(newProfile), {withCredentials: true, observe: 'response'}).subscribe(resp => {
        // Read the result field from the JSON response.
        console.log(resp.body); 
        });
}
```

To be able to execute request I need to pass authentication cookie. So I use:
`withCredentials: true`. However for some reason this does not work on Chrome (it refuse to send cookie). On Firefox and Edge it does work.

[image]

Comment: which version of angular you are using??

Comment: @Aravind   ^5.0.3

Comment: you should import the module `HttpClientXsrfModule`  and set the configuration

Comment: I configure it like this: `
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
  cookieName: '.AspNetCore.Identity.Application',
  headerName: 'Cookie'
})`
However it still does not work. Maybe I did not configure it right. there is no lot of documentation about how to use `HttpClientXsrfModule`

Comment: are you available in teamviewer or remote connect to debug and help you fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem.

`npm start` open site on `localhost` and I called api on `192.168.0.15` (in this case it is same PC as `localhost`, but I needed to open api for local network)

Firefox and Edge were ok with this setup. However Chrome was not. So I added:

```
"defaults": {
    "serve": {
        "host": "192.168.0.15"
},
```

to `.angular-cli.json` to make site load on `192.168.0.15` (same address as api) instead of default `localhost` and as result Chrome started sending cookie.